# GitHub API: How to get branch name from commit list?

Tags: git, github, github-api

Let's say I've got the following commits in my `master` branch.

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e
```

Then I create another branch called `feature`. I make a single commit on this branch. It looks like this.

```
                      <- f
a <- b <- c <- d <- e
```

When using the [list commits api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) I can get all commits for my `feature` branch. Is there a way to see from the result that my commit `f` is on the `feature` branch and the rest is in master?

Or do I have to make another request to the [compare two commits api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits)? In the end I'd like to have all commits (`a` - `f`) with the branch they belong to.

Edit:
`m` stands for `master` and `f` for `feature`.

```
branch: m <- m <- m <- m <- m <- f
commit: a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f
```

Answer (score 2):

(You already discovered the compare API; I include it below because it seems weird that they use another syntax.)

Commits A through E *are* in branch `feature`.

This is a big surprise to those used to other version control systems in which a commit is in *exactly one* branch.  In Git, commits are in *zero or more* branches.

To list commits that are in `feature` but are not in `master`, you tell Git: *Collect a set of all commits in `feature`.  Collect a second set of all commits in `master`.  Subtract the second set away from the first set, and show me the resulting set.*

The command-line syntax for this is `master..feature` or `feature ^master`.  Note that there are *two*, not *three*, dots between the two names.  The three-dot syntax exists as well, with a different meaning (symmetric difference—which is a superset of the two-dot meaning, but requires left side / right side indicators to be used to obtain the two-dot meaning).

[The GitHub API page suggests a REST API that may be equivalent.](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits)  Curiously, the REST API uses the *three*-dot syntax, but the description says it produces the same result as the two-dot syntax.  Whether it does, I do not know.